# How to solve with Thévenin's theorem

Tags: voltage, resistors, kirchhoffs-laws, thevenin

I have a question about this circuit when using Thévenin's theorem. The load is between the two points A and B. My only problem is how to explain to colleagues that when we remove the load between the two points A and B the voltage E<sub>Thévenin</sub> is not equal to that of the generator E2. This is a point that confuses me.

[image]

Comment: Rotate your picture please and don't draw a voltage source as a current source because it leads to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly there's no substitute for working through all the materials you'll easily find about Thévenin until it becomes easy.

But for explaining to others, I always recommend the "up-is-up scale graphical method", where you redraw your circuit with voltages and resistances to scale, (with positive upwards) like the following, and you measure with your ruler.

[image]

Comment: The way you have represented the diagram explains it better. At first I thought that point B was connected to the ground and that A would have 10 volts of voltage. But by calculating the current flowing in R2 and using the law of meshes I saw that the voltage between AB was 20 volts and I could not explain to others

Comment: Yes the staircase really helps: upstairs by 20V, downstairs by a quarter, upstairs again by 10V and you are indeed 25V above street level. But point B is itself upstairs by a quarter of 20V.

Answer (score 1):

You have drawn what are apparently voltage sources as current sources, also your image capture is pretty rough and rotated. It is better to use the schematic editor.

Anyway, if  you calculate the voltage across R2 with no load connected, you will see that it's in series with E2.

Comment: It seems there is a new method of indicating current and voltage sources but Mouh Kramo wrote that both are voltage sources even though one is a current source according to new circuit symbols of voltage and current sources.

Comment: @AmitM I half think you're kidding, but can you point me to where you learned of these new symbols?

Comment: Simon Fitch. These symbols look like Latex circuit symbols. They look european symbols in CircuiTikz. at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/CircuiTikz_package.

Answer (score 1):

E1, R1 and R0 are in series with nothing else connected between them, which means you can change their order without changing their combined behaviour. The first, easiest, simplification is to place R0 directly adjacent to R1, to reveal how those two are in series, and may be replaced with a single resistance R4:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo1i6V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we can convert E1, R4 and R2 to their Thévenin equivalent. Since the two resistors R4 and R2 have the same value, it's easy to see that the Thévenin voltage will be half of E1, and the Thévenin resistance will be half of R2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCIri0.png)</sup>

Now you have the same situation as you did at the start, where all components are in series, and their order can be changed. I'll move E2 to be adjacent to Eth1, to reveal how those two voltage sources simply add together:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f35LCK.png)</sup>

From there it's easy to show that the loaded voltage between A and B is 10V, and the unloaded (R3 removed) voltage is 20V. That's definitely not equal to E2, 10V.

Comment: Yes it's easier that way, Quick and More efficient

Answer (score 0):

When calculating Thevenin impedance or resistance across two terminals, you have to open circuit current sources and short circuit voltage sources looking from those terminals.

Comment: I'm asking about the voltage E_thevenin how Can I explain that the voltage in the Point A is not equal to the voltage E_2

Comment: To detect Thevenin voltage across A and B, remove the resistor between A and B and connect a 1A current source  between A and B while open circuiting current sources and short circuiting voltage sources in the circuit. Connect B to ground. Calculate \$V_A\$ which would be the Thevenin Voltage. You can use use nodal analysis to calculate \$V_A\$.. This technique works in DC circuits.